# Redireccionar a Sitio externo si no está loggeado

Tags: php, wordpress, login

Tengo un sitio **A** en Wordpress y un sitio **B** en PHP. Como puedo lograr que si un usario intenta entrar a mi sitio B sin estar loggeado en mi sitio A, sea redireccionado a la pagina del login de mi sitio A.

He buscado información sobre como redireccionar desde un formulario a una página externa, pero no he encontrado lo que necesito, pues en mi caso si se quisiera acceder desde la URL al sitio B directamente, automáticamente debe ser redireccionado al sitio A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una redirección desde .htaccess tomando como código de ejemplo:

```
Redirect 301 /directorio/documento-de-ejemplo.html http://www.ejemplo.es/ejemplo.html
```

O si lo prefieres puedes hacer un redireccionamiento desde un pequeño script en PHP ya sea en tu index.php del sitio **A** como el siguiente:

```
<?php
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.ejemplo.es");
exit;
?>
```

O también cuentas con la redirección desde el CPanel si es que cuentas con CPanel.

Comment: No cuento con CPanel. La solución que me muestras del script es la que creo puede solucionar mi problema. Ese pequeño script lo coloco en el index.php pero querras decir en mi sitio B, para que redireccione a mi sitio A para que el usuario se loggee.   De ser así entonces quedaría el segundo header así: header("Location: http://localhost/sitioB"); ??

Comment: Debería de ser así, prueba según las condiciones de tu sitio.